# Adding react-admin to existing project - resourceState is undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-admin

I was following the guide on https://marmelab.com/react-admin/CustomApp.html in order to incorporate react-admin to an existing react-redux project.

I have injected the admin, i18n and router state objects into a generic List component. However, when rendering the component, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: resourceState is undefined
mapStateToProps
node_modules/ra-core/lib/controller/ListController.js:413
410 | 
411 | return {
412 |     query: getQuery(props),
> 413 |     params: resourceState.list.params,
414 |     ids: resourceState.list.ids,
415 |     selectedIds: resourceState.list.selectedIds,
416 |     total: resourceState.list.total,
```

**An important remark is that when I `console.log` my component's props, I can see that the admin object indeed exists yet it contains no "resources" objects. How can I load resources manually into my store's admin?**

The component's smart container:

```
class MyContainer extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/admin/stuff/list' hasCreate render=
          {() => <MyList resource='myStuff' {...this.props}/>}/>
      </Switch>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) =>{
  return {
    admin: state.admin,
    i18n: state.i18n,
    form: state.form
  }
}
```

And finally, the MyList component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { List, Datagrid } from 'react-admin'

class MyList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <List {...this.props}>
        <Datagrid>
        </Datagrid>
      </List>
    )
  }
}

export default MyList
```

Comment: Yep, same problem here - going exactly according to the guide and getting the error too. Probably due to documentation being outdated. Took me couple months to realize how much terrible react-admin is, so I've decided to port the application over to better approach. Unfortunately, it's not that easy. I also saw your "issue" raised on GitHub where lib author redirects you to SO. Excellent approach React-Admin team! Not recommending this library to anybody.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to manually "registerResource".

So after you create your store do following:

```
import * as reactAdmin from "ra-core";
...
...
const store = createStore....


store.dispatch(reactAdmin.registerResource({
  name: "myStuff",
  hasList: true,
  hasEdit: false,
  hasShow: false,
  hasCreate: false
}));
```